# How to define Gradle tasks

Tags: gradle

I tried both versions defining tasks:

Version 1:

```
tasks {
    task helloWorld {
        group 'Testing'
        description "I don't do very much."
        println "I can print in configuration phase, too. I'm a big boy."
        doFirst {
            println 'Hello'
        }
        doLast {
            println "world"
        }
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
task helloWorld {
    group 'Testing'
    description "I don't do very much."
    println "I can print in configuration phase, too. I'm a big boy."
    doFirst {
        println 'Hello'
    }
    doLast {
        println "world"
    }
}
```

Is there any difference? In my opinion version 1 is way cleaner than version 2, especially working with multiple custom tasks and working with common conventions (https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html).

I want to get sure, I don't break anything, because I have never seen version 1 in any source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

- both versions are quite similar and will behave the same, but they both use the "old" Tasks API, creating tasks eagerly; you should consider switching to the "new" API [(since Gradle 4.9)](https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/release-notes.html#experimental-new-task-api) and configure tasks lazily, using `TaskContainer.register(...)` methods
- version 1 might seem cleaner to you but in fact it's way more confusing than version 2, I'll explain why.

### Long answer

##### Old Tasks API vs New Tasks API

In both version you are using the shorthand notation `task myTask { /* task configuration closure */ }`  which is a shortcut for [TaskContainer.create()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html#create-java.lang.String-groovy.lang.Closure-) method:

```
// following is equivalent to:
//  project.getTasks().create(...).configure( { /* tasks configuration */} )

tasks.create("myTask ") {   
    // task configuration closure
}
```

- this notation is specific to Groovy DSL, and will likely be deprecated in future Gradle releases - there will be no replacement for this notation in the new Tasks API (see more information [here](https://blog.gradle.org/preview-avoiding-task-configuration-time) and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:old_vs_new_configuration_api_overview))
- you should better use of the [Task configuration avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html) feature and declare your custom tasks lazily

##### Version 1 vs version 2

Version 2 is the way Gradle docs suggested for declaring tasks in older versions, e.g. [Helloworld in Gradle 5.6](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:hello_world)  (in latest versions the documentation references the new API: [Helloworld in Gradle 7.5](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:hello_world) )

In your version 1: there are two issues

###### `tasks` property collision

`project.tasks` could refer to either `Project.getTasks(): TaskContainer` property or to the `tasks` Task, thanks to [Dynamic Project properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#N14DEB):

```
tasks {
    // here we don't configure the project.TaskContainer as we could expect, but instead the default task named 'tasks'
    // proof:
    println " configuring task named: " + it.name
        // =>  configuring task named: tasks
    println " type of current object beeing configured: " + it.class.name
        // =>  type of current object beeing configured: org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.TaskReportTask_Decorated

    // this will still work, thanks to Groovy closure delegate feature :
    // will delegate to parent Project instance => equivalent to  project.task("helloWorld3") { /* config */ }
    task helloWorld3 {
        // tasks configuration
    }
}
```

funny (or not): this would also work, thanks to delegate mechanism:

```
repositories {
    task helloWorldDefinedInRepositories {
        // tasks configuration
    }
}
dependencies {
    task helloWorldDefinedInDependencies {
        // tasks configuration
    }
}
```

###### `tasks` (TaskContainer) methods

You could group custom tasks declaration under a common "parent" `tasks`  section as follows:

```
tasks.configure {
    // here we configure the Project.taskContainer  property.
    println " type of current object beeing configured: " + it.class.name
    // =>  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer_Decorated

    create("eagerTask") {
        // config
    }
    register("lazyTask") {
        // config
    }
}
```

This will work, but it's not clear why you think this will help in handling "common convention" , maybe you could give some more details about this expectation.